# How to discuss about time in an entirely empty space?

Tags: time, space

Assuming that there is a volume in universe where light havent reached yet from the beginning of the universe and every matter(or anything) is so far away from that it so no field from that even reached there yet so if we have to discuss about the presence of time there how can we say that time is also there yet...means how we can relate time to pure space(entirely empty space)? How to prove that time is there?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I would vote to close this question as it is based more on philosophy than physics, imo. If it does get closed , or if TBBT's answer is insufficient for you, could I suggest moving it to PhilosophySE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a philosophical question rather than a physically verifiable one.

Answer (score 0):

The perception of the passage of time is the increasing in entropy of the system. If your "supposedly volume of the universe does not change as it reaches maximum entropy, then there is no way to measure the passage of time. Therefore, time stands still.